# iOS 5 bug: UIWebView and goBack and goForward

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, ios5

I found a bug in iOS 5.

When you are using a UIWebView and access some sites, you create your history links, look like any other browser.

If you like to use a navegation bar, can use the functions `goBack` and `goForward`

In iOS 4.3 and below, when you call this function the program call the delegate function

```
webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
```

But in iOS 5.0 this can happens or not. If the site is in cache, it not call this function. I saw this happens in only 1 level (1 click in goBack or 1 to goFoward), in the second click it pass in the function.

Why they change it???? Even it is in cache, the program have to ask for me.. Now how solve this: I am trying make a stack with the browser history and I check the url. But i am having problem ;(

There are no other way?

- I can't see the browser history? I have to create my ow list?
- I can't clean the cache to force it pass in the function?

Any sugest?

Comment: It's not a bug in iOS 5. It's not loading, so it's not going to give you that callback. If you want to build a stack of user history, then you need to save the requests external to the web view when they go `forward`.

Comment: It is a bug for me, because I have to check some pages and than make some actions. But because it didn't give-me a callback, how can I do this?

Comment: If you genuinely feel it's a bug file a report at bugreport.apple.com

Comment: There's no such thing as 'a bug for me'. You're relying on the wrong UIWebView behaviour. Abhi's answer is what I was getting at.

Comment: @Jessedc, lol you are correct. 'a bug for me' is not a good thing to say...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a bug, if there is enough available RAM on the device then it will keep some of the pages in memory, therefore they are not being "loaded" again when you go back.

You should create your own `goBack:` and `goForward:` actions on your own controller, and link the goBack/goForward buttons to them:

```
- (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender
{
    [self doStuff];

    [self.webView goBack:sender];
}
```